# How many 3 letter words can you form from 'EEAAP'

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> How many 3 letter words can you form from 'EEAAP'

I think the answer is

${3\choose 3} * 3!  + {2\choose 1} * 3 + {2\choose 1} *3=18$. Is this right?

${3\choose 3} * 3!$  = You pick all distinct

${2\choose 1} * 3$ = You pick 2 e's and either a or p

${2\choose 1} * 3$= You pick 2 a's and either e or p

Comment: Your result is right.

Comment: Calculus : Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The words with three different letters are the rearrangement of "AEP" so are $3!=6$. The words with two different letters are rearrangement of AAP,AAE,EEA,EEP so 12. So i get a total of 18.